# Order of evaluation in initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Does the following initializations of valueA and valueB entail undefined behavior?

```
int array[2] = {1,2};
int index = 0;
int valueA = array[index++], valueB = array[index++];
```

Is there any change in this between c++ 98 and c++ 11?

Comment: why would you do this? you save exactly one typing of the keyword int.

Comment: How about finding bugs in existing code? Or just wanting to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is well-defined. From C++11 draft n3290 §8 *Declarators*:

> Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
...
int valueA = array[index++];
int valueB = array[index++];
```

I don't have a C++98 standard, but the same wording is present in ISO/IEC 14882:2003 ("C++03").

Comment: but that doesn't fix the order of the two initializations, for that you need the sequence point induced by the comma.

Comment: A declaration by itself is a full expression. You get a sequence point after a full expression.

Comment: A declaration is not even an expression, but `array[index++]` is a full expression.

Answer (score 0):

not undefined behavior.
the comma is [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: There is no comma operator in there.

Comment: @rhalbersma: that's not a comma operator.

Comment: ah thanks. I see on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator that you are right!